# XSLT: output &quot; without it being parsed

Tags: parsing, xslt, quotes

I am trying to achieve the following XML output:

```
<Foo bar="&quot;" />
```

My XSLT file is as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:variable name="quote">
            <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:variable>

        <Foo bar="{$quote}"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately, this gives me the output:

```
<Foo bar="&#34;"/>
```

How do I alter my XSLT to output & quot; without it being parsed into either a " character or a & #34;?

Comment: Why does it matter?  The two are equivalent (and there are various other equivalent ways to say the same thing too, for example `<Foo bar='"'/>`) and an XML parser won't tell an application which way it was written in the source, the app just sees an attribute whose value is a double-quote character.

Comment: You make a wonderful point. I has been aiming to output XML in a particular format - to match what Microsoft Excel appeared to want, but you're right that Excel parses the file properly even if &#34; is used.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ian Roberts has already made the very good point that it doesn't actually matter. But if you really, really wanted to do this, then in XSLT 2.0 (but not XSLT 1.0) you could make use of a character map, like so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" use-character-maps="quotes" />

    <xsl:character-map name="quotes">
        <xsl:output-character character="&quot;" string="&amp;quot;" />
    </xsl:character-map>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="quote">
            <xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:variable>

        <Foo bar="{$quote}"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```